Problem reading files from obb expansion file
I face a problem when trying to play an audio file located inside the expansion file in the phone's internal memory
private void playSelectedSong(String songName) {
        String obbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/com.mesbahi.free.player/main.1.com.mesbahi.free.player.obb";
        try {
            ZipFile obbZipFile = new ZipFile(obbPath);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = obbZipFile.entries();

            boolean fileFound = false;
            while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
                ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if(entry.getName().startsWith(songName)){
                    InputStream inputStream = obbZipFile.getInputStream(entry);
                    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(songName, "."+getFileExtension(entry), getCacheDir());
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
                    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
                    player.prepare();
                    player.play();
                    player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
                    fileFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!fileFound) {
                Intent fileNotFoundIntent = new Intent("com.mesbahi.free.player.FILE_NOT_FOUND");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(fileNotFoundIntent);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent updateButtonIntent = new Intent("com.mesbahi.free.player.UPDATE_BUTTON_STATE");
        updateButtonIntent.putExtra("isPlaying", true);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(updateButtonIntent);

    }


    private String getFileExtension(ZipEntry entry){
        String name = entry.getName();
        int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (lastIndexOf == -1) {
            return "";
        }
        return name.substring(lastIndexOf);
    }

The code works correctly on Android versions 13 or lower
The bug only appears in Android version 14, and this appears in the logcat :
FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.mesbahi.free.player/main.1.com.mesbahi.free.player.obb (Permission denied)

Use context.getObbDir() instead and make sure to request permissions like
    String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // no permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    1
            );
        }
    }

and add
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

to manifest

It didn't work
It also clarified that the error only appears in Android 14
